# 503 service is unavailable in Analytics Reporting API V4

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

Sample Call:
https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json

Sample Error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 503 when requesting https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "The service is currently unavailable.". Details: "The service is currently unavailable.">

Calling it once an hour instead of backoff fails every time. Then, after a day or two, it intermittently succeeds. Only one account has a problem. The rest is fine.

code:

```py
        query = {
            "reportRequests": [
                {
                    "viewId": str(view_id),
                    "dateRanges": [
                        {
                            "startDate": "2022-11-29",
                            "endDate": "2022-11-29",
                        }
                    ],
                    "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"}, {"expression": "ga:newUsers"}, {"expression": "ga:transactions"}],
                    "dimensions": [{"name": "ga:source"}, {"name": "ga:medium"}, {"name": "ga:campaign"}, {"name": "ga:adContent"},
                    "pageSize": 100_000,
                }
            ]
        }

        return service.reports().batchGet(body=query).execute()
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Even if you haven't asked any question, let me ask one: did you ask Google's support about this? If an API endpoint returns an error, most of the time other developers cannot help

Comment: I can't contact google. The web page directed me to stackoverflow.

Comment: "I can't contact google" - why not?

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] we cnt help unless we can run your code.

Comment: i'm start was here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236721235. Users can no longer register issues on the tracker. Instead, go to the following link. https://developers.google.com/analytics/help/  . And the google page guides you through stackoverflow.

Comment: @DaImTo thank you. Similar to the code in the official documentation(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py). The problem doesn't appear on all accounts. So I think there is no problem with the code.

Comment: @jay please edit your question and include [example] in your question not a link to it we need to see **YOUR** code if we are to help.   you may want to read [ask]

Comment: @DaImTo update completed! :)

Answer (score 2):

First off 500 errors are something is wrong on Googles end.  There is nothing you can do to fix it.  Its often caused by the server being over loaded, and your script timing out.

A tip would be to never run on the hour, everyone that has a cron job set up has it set to run on the hour and your going to be completing for server processing with everyone else.

I cant see anything wrong with the code you have.

PRO tip. the google apis python client library has back off built in.  So if your seeing a 500 error the library has already retried the call about ten times before you are even seeing the error.

Comment: i know. but, I get a 503 error very frequently. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Seeing as UA analytics is shutting down i would expect that a lot of people are trying to export their data these says.  I wouldn't be surprised if the servers are just in general overloaded.

Comment: I have many GA accounts. 503 errors occur frequently with certain accounts. Are there any possible causes?